# Order of acidity of water, an alcohol, an amine, and acetylene

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

> What is the order of acidity of $\ce{H2O}$, $\ce{ROH}$, $\ce{RNH2}$, $\ce{C2H2}$?

I began by forming the conjugate base of each. The conjugate bases are as follows $\ce{-OH}$, $\ce{-RO}$, $\ce{-RNH}$, $\ce{-C2H}$.

Between stability of $\ce{-OH}$ and $\ce{-ROH}$, $\ce{-ROH}$ is more unstable. Also, in $\ce{-RNH}$, the negative charge is on nitrogen atom making it more unstable than the other two groups.

In $\ce{-C2H}$ the pi elctron cloud will face repulsion of with the negative charge on the carbon atom.

So by this logic, decreasing order of acidity should be:

$$\ce{H2O > ROH > RNH2 > C2H2}$$

But the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values suggest the very reverse order. What is the fault in my reasoning?

Comment: If you just start with being able to rationalize the difference in acidity between ammonia and water, you're more than half way to the answer.

Comment: @Zhe Sois my answer correct

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, acetylene should be more acidic than a primary amine.

Answer (score 1):

According to

$$
\begin{array}{lc}
\hline
\text{Compound} & \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} \\
\hline
\text{Water} & 15.7 \\
\text{Methanol} & 16.0 \\
\text{Methylamine} & 36.0 \\
\text{Ethyne} & 25 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

the order of acidity is

$$\text{water} > \text{methanol} > \text{ethyne} > \text{methylamine}$$

You logic is absolutely correct, but only there is an exception in case of electronegativities of $\mathrm{sp}$ carbon and $\mathrm{sp^3}$ nirogen.

The $\mathrm{sp}$ carbon is more electronegative than $\mathrm{sp^3}$ nitrogen and hence ethyne is more acidic here. The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values also tell you the same story.

Answer (score -3):

pKa values are -logKa.

Ka is the dissociation constant of the acid

Smaller the Ka value, weaker is the acid.

Therefore, pka values will go on decreasing from strong acid to weak acid.

Comment: I think everybody knows that

Comment: @starunique2016 I wouldn't assume that. But I agree that this may not answer the OP's question. It's not clear to me what they're confused about...

Comment: I don't know the pka values of the given compounds, and I'm assuming that the person asking the question has got his Ka and Pka mixed up, which is why I wrote the answer.

Comment: Yep but certainly this is not an answer with definite reasoning.

Comment: I can't post an answer with definite reasoning, because I don't know the Pka values, and so, I can't examine the trends in them. I think the OP's reasoning behind the acidity order is right, so the only confusion is in the Pka values. I can't comment due to lack of reputation, otherwise I would've done that